# Ubuntu persistence error

Tags: boot, partitioning, persistence

I've been attempting to create a persistent version of Ubuntu using gparted. After allocating a new partition and trying to format it to ext4, I'm getting errors saying that partitions inside of my persistent partition don't exist:

GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Format /dev/sdb3p1 as ext4  00:00:03    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sdb3p1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb3p1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 238405631
size: 238403584 (113.68 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb3p1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 122062110720  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 122062569472  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 122062626816  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdb3  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sdb3p1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: ext4
create new ext4 file system  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

mkfs.ext4 -F -O ^64bit -L '' '/dev/sdb3p1'  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The file /dev/sdb3p1 does not exist and no size was specified.
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sdb3 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes.

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please describe with more details, what you mean by a persistent version of Ubuntu. I can think of three kinds of Ubuntu systems: 1. Live-only (created by cloning from the Ubuntu iso file to a USB pendrive); 2. Persistent live (using a casper-rw file or partition to store the data to persist reboot and shutdown); 3. Installed system (standard installation [like] into the internal drive). Such a system is persistent too, but the term 'persistent' is not used for it. -- I use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a persistent live system with a casper-rw partition.

Comment: I'm trying to do number two, Persistent live, I tried using mkusb but it seemed to screw up the iso files, I got numerous errors on boot saying that it was missing. So now I'm trying to use gparted to make a persistent section on the usb.

Comment: mkusb does not screw up iso files, it clones them (also when making a persistent live drive: partition #4 will contain a cloned copy of the iso file. Cloning is a very robust process. Please check with **md5sum**, that the downloaded iso file is good (that it matches the listed md5sum). See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes